# unix find and multiple commands to find all files, exclude a dir, and base results on time

Tags: find

Given a folder, I want to ignore a folder within, and then find all files outside that folder, whether they be folders or files, and eventually delete them via a cron style action on OS X.

On Mac OS X  will use Launchd to run this, so far, I have this:

```
find /Users/me/Downloads -not \( -path /Users/me/Downloads/In\ Progress -prune \) -name "*" -Btime 1m
```

With the `-Btime 1m` or `mime 1m` I get zero results, without it i get results I can exec to rm:

```
find /Users/me/Downloads -not \( -path /Users/me/Downloads/In\ Progress -prune \) -name "*"
/Users/me/Downloads
/Users/me/Downloads/.DS_Store
/Users/me/Downloads/test
/Users/me/Downloads/text.txt
```

Eventually my criteria will be 1 week, but for now, I use 1 minute, as that surely has passed.

```
cd ~/Downloads
$find . -mtime 1m
$
```

Or

```
cd ~/Downloads
$find . -mtime 1m -print
$find: *: unknown primary or operator
```

Comment: I just cobbled this from an old script I remembered, anyone see any issues: $/usr/bin/find /Users/me/Downloads -not \( -path /Users/me/Downloads/In\ Progress -prune \) -mtime +1s

Comment: /usr/bin/find /Users/me/Downloads -not \( -path /Users/me/Downloads/In\ Progress -prune \) -mtime +1s           Unfortuneately, this finds the Downloads dir as well, which would mean I will nuke that too.  I could set perms on it to not allow my user to delete it, or I could run an if loop around the results, and exclude it, but there should I would like to learn how to nest commands in the parenthesis if possible within the find command.  Thanks,

Comment: I'm a bit confused what the actual issue you're having is, it looks like you're not finding any files because the `inode` was not created exactly 1 minute ago for any files, but not sure if that's the issue or not. In your last comment you're not pruning or otherwise omitting `Downloads`, but `/Users/me/Downloads/In\ Progress`?

Comment: The files certainly are old enough, they are hours old now. :)  The man page says nothing specific about exactly 1 minute, is it not 60 seconds or less ago?  Or did I read that wrong?  I am looking for files older than 60 seconds in testing, and older than 1w in production.  I believe I solved it, but want to post another issue that I can't do in these little comment boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I figured it out, but if someone could look over my shoulder, I certainly would appreciate it:

/usr/bin/find /Users/$USER/Downloads -not ( -path /Users/$USER/Downloads/In\ Progress -prune -o -type d ) -mtime +1s

That finds all files in ~/Downloads at are older than 1 second(s) and are not inside the "In Progress" directory.  At first, it was also locating the path /Users/$USER/Downloads as the first hit

```
/usr/bin/cd ~/Downloads/
echo "You are in: " $(/bin/pwd)
/usr/bin/find /Users/$USER/Downloads -not \( -path /Users/$USER/Downloads/In\ Progress -prune -o -type d \) -mtime +1s
```

So, can anyone tell me why it is not picking up /Users/$USER/Downloads I certainly don't mind, but I also don't like not understanding.

Finally, the last step would be, change mime to +1w and then append xargs rm -rf {} \; and I should be good to go?  If I also wanted to pass in a little list of what find has found and >> it to a log file, where would be a good place to shove that?